# Why does this phpmyadmin setup not work? Using Docker and MariaDB

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Apologies if I use the incorrect terminology. I have an nginx webserver. I had three Docker containers running on this server- [SWAG](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/swag), [MariaDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb), and [phpMyAdmin](https://hub.docker.com/_/phpmyadmin). I then followed [this guide](https://migueldoctor.medium.com/run-mariadb-phpmyadmin-locally-in-3-steps-using-docker-6b5912ff37c9) to link phpMyAdmin, though I had to use the `--network [network_name]` option when I used `docker run`. Now, when I run `docker ps` [this is the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAYRl.png), so I would expect to be able to access phpmyadmin by going to the webserver's address and appending :8080. However, this results in the connection timing out.

I tried accessing [webserver IP]:8080 to access phpMyAdmin and edit the data in MariaDB. I would expect phpMyAdmin to be accessible, but the server just times out. I am able to access the rest of the server as normal.

Comment: What do the container logs for phpMyAdmin say? `--link` is deprecated. Recommend going a docker compose path for reproducibility and share that.